# Looking for the source of a saying on "redemption being like a candle in the daylight"

Tags: sources-mekorot, quotations, lighting, daytime, ymoth-hamoshiach

I'm looking for the source for the saying that goes something like: "celebrating the first redemption in the yemos hamoshiach will be like lighting a candle in the daylight".

Comment: welcome Yisroel Nachum. interesting image.

Comment: Hello Yisroel Nachum and welcome to Mi Yodeya

If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: ישועת ה' כהרף עין

Answer (score 2):

I think it's two Gemaras put together.

One is in Shabbos 63a. It says

> תניא אמרו לו לרבי אליעזר וכי מאחר דתכשיטין הן לו מפני מה הן בטלין לימות המשיח אמר להן לפי שאינן צריכין שנאמר לא ישא גוי אל גוי חרב ותהוי לנוי בעלמא אמר אביי מידי דהוה אשרגא בטיהרא

The subject is whether arms are considered jewelry. Rabbi Eliezer says it is and the sages say it's not. The source for those who say that weapons are not jewelry is the verse which says that when Moshiach will come, the nations will beat their swords into plowshares. If swords are jewelry, why not keep them as ornamental swords? Rabbi Eliezar said that since it would be *like a candle in the day*, as in so completely useless that it looses even its ornamental status.

There's another Gemara in Berachos (12b-13a) which says

> תניא אמר להם בן זומא לחכמים וכי מזכירין יציאת מצרים לימות המשיח והלא כבר נאמר הנה ימים באים נאם ה' ולא יאמרו עוד חי ה' אשר העלה את בני ישראל מארץ מצרים כי אם חי ה' אשר העלה ואשר הביא את זרע בית ישראל מארץ צפונה ומכל הארצות אשר הדחתים שם אמרו לו לא שתעקר יציאת מצרים ממקומה אלא שתהא שעבוד מלכיות עיקר ויציאת מצרים טפל לו כיוצא בו אתה אומר לא יקרא שמך עוד יעקב כי אם ישראל יהיה שמך לא לא שיעקר יעקב ממקומו אלא ישראל עיקר ויעקב טפל לו וכן הוא אומר אל תזכרו ראשונות וקדמוניות אל תתבוננו אל תזכרו ראשונות זה שעבוד מלכיות וקדמוניות אל תתבוננו זו יציאת מצרים הנני עושה חדשה עתה תצמח תני רב יוסף זו מלחמת גוג ומגוג משל למה הדבר דומה לאדם שהיה מהלך בדרך ופגע בו זאב וניצל ממנו והיה מספר והולך מעשה זאב פגע בו ארי וניצל ממנו והיה מספר והולך מעשה ארי פגע בו נחש וניצל ממנו שכח מעשה שניהם והיה מספר והולך מעשה נחש אף כך ישראל צרות אחרונות משכחות את הראשונות

This discusses the famous Mishna (which is in the Haggadah) where Rabbi Elazar ben Azaria said that he is like a seventy year old man and couldn't find a source that one must mention the Exodus at night, but the sages (who say one doesn't) uses that verse to prove that one has to mention the Exodus when Moshiach will come.

Ben Azzai, on the other hand, says that when Moshiach will come, the Jewish people will no longer mention the Exodus and will only mention our upcoming redemption. He says a parable that after a person escapes from wolf, he talks about this escapade, but once he is saved from a lion and a snake, he forgets all other redemptions and only focuses on the last one

Answer (score -1):

These are apparently kabalistic ideas found in some Habad writings, e.g.,

R Yosef Karasik writes [here](http://www.beismoshiach.org/_pdf/732.pdf) (p. 22, bottom right)

> In Yemos HaMoshiach, Purim will be celebrated and the other holidays
>   will be nullified because the G-dly revelation on those holidays will
>   be **eclipsed by the powerful G-dly revelation of that time, just like
>   the light of a candle is negligible in broad dayligh**t.

See also [here](http://www.beismoshiach.org/_pdf/409.pdf) (p. 7, bottom left) refererring to a sicha of the Lubavitcher Rebbe (Shabbos parshas Shmini, parshas Hachodesh, 5th day of Adar II, 5749)

> In particular, the concept of “a candle” refers to a torch, while “a
>   light” refers to the daylight and, ultimately, to the light that will
>   be revealed in the Messianic Age when “**the light of the sun will be
>   seven times the light of the seven days [of creation]**.” On an even
>   higher level, it refers to the revelation of the Divine light in that
>   era when, “**the sun will no longer serve you for [the purpose of]
>   daylight..., [but] G-d will be an eternal light for you.**”